Cannot install pip for Python 3.12.3 - unmet dependencies and error processing package systemd
I should start this by saying I am a beginner when it comes to both Python and Ubuntu so this may be a silly question.
I am trying to install pip on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (using WSL) but having some issues. When i try running sudo apt-get install python3-pip I get the following output:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pip : Depends: python3-wheel but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: build-essential but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: python3-dev (>= 3.2) but it is not going to be installed
 systemd-sysv : Depends: systemd (= 255.4-1ubuntu8) but 255.4-1ubuntu8.2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

After running the suggested code sudo apt --fix-broken install I get the following output:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  systemd-sysv
The following packages will be upgraded:
  systemd-sysv
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 72 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/11.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up systemd (255.4-1ubuntu8.2) ...
Failed to take /etc/passwd lock: Invalid argument
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 installed systemd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

As a novice I do not understand what the error messages on the second output mean and how to fix the problems, if anyone could explain to me in simple terms what the error means and if you have any suggestions on how to fix the issue so I can install pip it would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

The version of Ubuntu is not only needed it is critical in any question that involves Python. Python is used by many of the Ubuntu apps and features. Please edit the question and add the version of Ubuntu that you are using.

Did you run apt --fix-broken install with sudo, i.e. sudo apt --fix-broken install?

Also, you have 72 packages not upgraded. You should probably run sudo apt full-upgrade to ensure you have all security upgrades installed.

@ArturMeinild thank you very much for your suggestions. Yes, I did originally use sudo to run the fix broken install command. I have just ran sudo apt full-upgrade and got the following output:   'Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
systemd-sysv : Depends: systemd (= 255.4-1ubuntu8) but 255.4-1ubuntu8.2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).'

@ArturMeinild
I then tried sudo apt --fix-broken install again as suggested but am still getting the same error I got originally.
The code in my comment above does mention I am not using the correct version of Ubuntu - would you recommend I I try getting the version of Ubuntu that is recommended in the code and try installing pip again?

Hmm I think there is a dependency problem that I can't really figure out then.

@ArturMeinild I have just tried uninstalling Ubuntu 24.02 and instead installed Ubuntu 22.04 and could get pip fine on this older version. Not too sure why it wasnt working on the latest release.
